Wallet censorship options in Substrate DAOs
I looked at the various governance options in the Polkadot documentation and haven't found any options for dealing with bad actors (mostly validators, but could be others such as attackers).

I know that's by design (permissionless, anti-censorship, etc.) and there's slashing, but that aside - what options are available should that become required?
For an example, some DAOs can perform emergency shutdowns [1].

On Substrate chains, it appears that "censorship" would be performed by the Technical Committee acting on proposals. Whose proposals?

I assume those proposals must be approved, not just "proposed". Considering that voting in the council or a referendum may take a while (days), how can that address "emergencies"?

Does anyone know of any examples on a Substrate chain that we can learn from?


[1] https://www.quillaudits.com/blog/web3-security/dao-governance-attacks

Recent example:
https://polkadot.polkassembly.io/referenda/1339
